# ifelse by column position in r - column name is not known

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `ifelse()` inside a `dplyr::mutate()` call, but I do not necessarily know the column name. Although, this column will always be the first column, so I know its position. Is there a way I can do this?

**Reprex using column name:**

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

tibble(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) %>% 
  mutate(z = ifelse(x < 4, "a", "b"))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        x       y z    
#>    <int>   <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     1  1.03   a    
#>  2     2 -0.600  a    
#>  3     3  0.0364 a    
#>  4     4  0.986  b    
#>  5     5 -0.815  b    
#>  6     6  0.166  b    
#>  7     7 -0.607  b    
#>  8     8 -0.719  b    
#>  9     9  0.799  b    
#> 10    10 -0.947  b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now I need to do the same, by using the column position (1) instead. Like: `ifelse(**position 1** < 4, "a", "b")`.

This has to be inside a `dplyr::mutate` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### dplyr >= 1.0

Since `1.0`, `dplyr` provides the `cur_data()` function which is better than abusing the `.` from the pipe operator, and ensures this solution accurately works with grouped data.

```r
tibble(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) %>% 
    mutate(z = ifelse(cur_data()[[1]] < 4, "a", "b"))
```

##### Original answer

Reference column at index `i` using `.[[i]]`.

```r
tibble(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) %>% 
  mutate(z = ifelse(.[[1]] < 4, "a", "b"))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        x       y z    
#>    <int>   <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     1  0.255  a    
#>  2     2 -0.0805 a    
#>  3     3 -0.553  a    
#>  4     4 -0.492  b    
#>  5     5 -1.80   b    
#>  6     6  0.199  b    
#>  7     7 -0.397  b    
#>  8     8  1.06   b    
#>  9     9  1.72   b    
#> 10    10 -0.248  b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference columns by their index instead of name, using brackets directly following the dataframe.

E.g. `ifelse(df[1] < 4, "a", "b")`